The Mitzva to Know Hashem = get to know Him. Diyyuk in Mishneh Torah?
I once heard Rabbi Manis Friedman Shlita prove, from the wording or some other clever diyuk, in the first perek of Mishneh Torah, that the Mitzva of (paraphrased) "knowing that there is a first cause... i.e. Hashem" doesn't just mean knowing He exists, but that the halacha is to get to know Him. Does anyone know what his diyuk was, or fancy trying to figure it out for themselves?

He is a master at diyukim on hashkafa like this :) Therefore the best answer would be the one that knows which shiur I am talking about and can bring it (or even better - his original source in Chassidut Chabad). That's unlikely* so I am prepared to accept an answer or at least +1 that makes sense on its own, especially if it feels familiar to me. Shkoyach.

* he has literally thousands. I seem to remember that it was most likely one of his Zoom shiurim, but failing that, it might have been one of the shiurim he just gives to his camera, with a black background  - I think on his main channel. Don't go on any red herrings and bittul zman based on this "scanty" information.

The first thing that comes to mind is that in Yesodei Hatorah 1:10 the Rambam explains Moses' knowledge of God by analogy to knowledge of a person using language (עד שהשיג מאמיתת המצאו דבר שנפרד הקב"ה בדעתו משאר הנמצאים) that closely resembles his definition of the mitzva in 1:1 (וכל הנמצאים משמים וארץ ומה שביניהם לא נמצאו אלא מאמתת המצאו)

The Rambam does this consistently with mitzvos that would appear to be all in the mind. In Yesodei haTorah 2:2, a parallel shift is made in defining Ahavas Hashem. In Teshuvah 1:1 we are told the mitzvah itself is the Vidui, not the Teshuvah. (כְּשֶׁיַּעֲשֶׂה תְּשׁוּבָה וְיָשׁוּב מֵחֶטְאוֹ חַיָּב לְהִתְוַדּוֹת לִפְנֵי הָקל בָּרוּךְ הוּא) And to give an example that's a lav, Lo Sachmod is about חִמּוּד שֶׁיֵּשׁ בּוֹ מַעֲשֶׂה -- a desire that is acted upon (Gezeilah vaAveidah 1:9).

But I think it has more to do with the Rambam's definition of "mitzvah" than whether in practice one must believe. After all, to the Rambam, knowledge (justified belief in something true) is the key to Olam haBa, Hashgachah Peratis, Nevu'ah, Vehalakha biDerakhav (and thus key to the right way to have good Middos), etc, etc, etc...

@MichaBerger Could you expand? It would be a tremendous honour to hear your thoughts on this in full
